# ID´s duplicados em consulta sql

Tags: sql

amigos tenho uma consulta assim:

```
SELECT v.product_id,nome AS Produto,presentation AS Descricao, 
    presentation    AS Descricao2, name1 AS categoria, 
    description_two AS descricao, price AS preco, 
    quantity AS estoque, width, height, depth, weight, 
    NAME, referenceCode, datapostagem 
FROM Variant v 
    INNER JOIN ProductCategory p ON v.product_id = p.product_id 
    INNER JOIN Product ON Product.id = p.product_id 
    INNER JOIN Category ON Category.id = category_id 
    INNER JOIN Image i ON i.product_id = p.product_id 
    INNER JOIN DescriptionGroup D ON D.product_id = p.product_id 
    INNER JOIN Stock S ON S.variant_id = v.id 
    INNER JOIN DimensionGroup G ON G.variant_id = v.id 
LIMIT   10
```

e nesta consulta me retornar muitos product_id duplicados como posso criar um SUM ou para separar os duplicados em outra tabela ?

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador do banco de dados?  mariaDB, Oracle Database, PostgreSQL etc?

Comment: mysql, phpmyadmin

Comment: Não é que está trazendo duplicado, e sim porque pode conter + de 1 registro em uma tabela referenciada por `JOIN`, em relação a tabela principal `Variant`.